# Assign query argument as names to lists returned by a query in python

Tags: python

variable list  "list_ids".

This id I want as list name.

```
list_ids=  [1,44,37]
for id in list_ids:
    cursor.execute("SELECT distinct [instance] from table where id=?",id) 
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    instances = [rw[0] for rw in row]
    print instances
```

this generated 3 different lists for the 3 elements of list "list_ids".

trying to assign the 3 elements of list "list_ids" as names for the generated lists.

Comment: This returns 3 lists like
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
How do I get;
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
list_44 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_37 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Please note that list_ids is a variable list and number of list elements differ in it

Comment: Cool. Did you have a question? Edit: edit your original post to contain the question.

Comment: How do I get:
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] 
list_44 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
list_37 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: How does it return 3 lists? Are they also in a list? Does it return [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] [1,2,3,4,5,6] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]? In that case you can do list_1, list_44, list37 = get_instance()

Comment: no they come up as 3 different lists as the query under an iterator             "for id in list_ids:" 
And I am printing inside the iterator

Comment: Python is a whitespace language, can you reformat your code so that it's not all on one line? Then it would make sense and actually be readable to us.

Comment: Formatted the code. Please check

Comment: Thanks. And are you trying to store the three instances in three named variables called list_1, list_44, and list_37, or do you want to store all three in the same thing, so that the first list is d[1], the second is d[44], and the third is d[37]?

Comment: I am trying to store the three instances in three named variables called list_1, list_44, and list_37. So what ever value is in the where clause of the query, the resultant list should be named with that value having "list_" as prefix

Comment: Why? If you make the variable names dynamic you won't be able to refer to them in the rest of the script, which is what variables are for. Are you sure you don't want a container object?

Comment: I need the variable names in the same fashion, but I also need to refer to them through out the script. Throughout the script I need to refer to the list  [1,2,3,4,5,6] when ever I do something for id 44. Please help